# Any way to programatically trigger global mediakeys in Windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows, triggers, media-player, hotkeys

Is there any way to programatically trigger global mediakeys in Windows using Java?
I want to trigger the global hotkeys that mediaplayers are listening to.
Is this possible in Java or maybe in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys also just have keycodes, and keycode constants all just map to byte values, so: Get a for-loop, an byte-variable, and fire all after another which in the end will give you the expected result :)

Maybe you have to add modifiers, the linux keymap files for your keyboard of choice should give you hints about your keys.